# First connection to Ansible : permission denied

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a VM and one vps which both run on Centos 7.

I created an ansible inventory file which contains :

```
vps_ip ansible_user=root
```

I got an error : Authentification or permission failure.

I don't understand cause I already copied ssh keys on my vps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ansible which key to use in...

```
#/etc/ansible.cfg.
private_key_file = /path/to/your/.ssh/id_rsa
```